# Reporting Jest Test run result in a file

Tags: jestjs

I am new to Jest. I am able to set it up and write my Jest tests and execute from the `package.json` by specifying another target like this in a Node-16.x environment.

```
 "test": "jest -config=jest.config.json"
 "test-cov": "jest -config=jest.config.json --coverage"
```

Now what I want is that: I want to save the run reports in a file -- which I will later on share over email to notify the report.

In effect, what I am looking for are:

1. In case I am running *without* `--coverage` - how can I save the PASS/FAIL report in a file in a specified location (like  report_dir/report_service.)
2. In case I am running with `--coverage` - how can I save the PASS/FAIL report in a file in a specified location (like  report_dir/report__coverage_service.)

Answer (score 2):

The jest configuration one can specify the reports. Even including custom reports also.

The options can be checked [Jest Reporting](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#reporters-arraymodulename--modulename-options) and [Jest Coverage Reporting](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#reporters-arraymodulename--modulename-options)

All the Jest config options can be found here: [Configuring Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration)

Answer (score 1):

You can add cli flags `--json --outputFile=output.json`

Such as:

```
jest --config jestconfig.json --coverage --detectOpenHandles --json --outputFile=output.json
```